# Check in file using CSOM in O365

Tags: 2013, office-365, csom

I tried the below code

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Sites/SiteName/Style Library/JS/app.js");
if (home.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
{
   home.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
}
```

`home.CheckOutType` is throwing an error as that property is not initialized

> Message   "The property or field 'CheckOutType' has not been
>   initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been
>   executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."    string

Will it not work in O365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the file first before checking it in. Try the below code:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Sites/SiteName/Style Library/JS/app.js");

ctx.Load(home);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


if (home.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
{
   home.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
}
```